# For loop incorrect number of dimensions in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I am attempting to create a matrix of response probabilities by looping through the rows of a vector (theta) and columns of separate matrix (tmp). I keep receiving the error message `incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`and am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
theta = seq(from=-4, to=4, by=.01)

ID = c(1:10)
a = c(1.11,1.03,1.03,1.62,1.23,1.16,1.46,0.91,0.78,0.85)
b = c(-0.33,0.05,-1.25,-0.18,0.47,-1.11,-0.17,-0.57,-0.18,0.45)
c = c(0.16,0.18,0.17,0.24,0.12,NA,NA,NA,0.29,NA)

tmp = data.frame(ID,a,b,c)

for (j in 1:nrow(tmp)) {
  for (k in 1:length(theta)){
  RP[k,j] = tmp$c[j] + ((1-tmp$c[j])/
                (1+exp(-1.7 * tmp$a[j]*theta - tmp$b[j])))
  }
}
```

The desired results is a matrix with the same number of rows as the length of theta and the same number of columns as the tmp data frame. It should look like this:

```
head(tmp2)
         p1        p2        p3        p4        p5 p6 p7 p8        p9 p10
1 0.1603182 0.1807822 0.1702159 0.2400104 0.1203281 NA NA NA 0.2929362  NA
2 0.1603243 0.1807960 0.1702197 0.2400107 0.1203350 NA NA NA 0.2929752  NA
3 0.1603305 0.1808100 0.1702236 0.2400110 0.1203421 NA NA NA 0.2930148  NA
4 0.1603368 0.1808243 0.1702276 0.2400113 0.1203493 NA NA NA 0.2930549  NA
5 0.1603432 0.1808389 0.1702316 0.2400116 0.1203567 NA NA NA 0.2930955  NA
6 0.1603497 0.1808537 0.1702357 0.2400120 0.1203642 NA NA NA 0.2931366  NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last line of the `for` loop, you are using the whole of vector theta as a multiplier:

```
(1+exp(-1.7 * tmp$a[j]*theta - tmp$b[j])))
```

Presumably you meant to use the kth element:

```
(1+exp(-1.7 * tmp$a[j]*theta[k] - tmp$b[j])))
```

I can't test this as you've left out the definition of the matrix RP, but I'm sure you didn't mean to return 801 elements every pass through the loop.

Comment: Thank you! Part of the problem was that I had not defined the matrix RP ahead of time. Your comment clued me in. After also adding the kth element to theta the loop finally works. I appreciate it!